# Why won't my PC display to my TV?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, vga, tv

I've got a desktop computer running Windows 7, with an "Inter(R) 82945g Express Chipset Family" video card.

I also have a Sony Bravia KDL-40S5100 TV, which has a VGA port.

I can hook the desktop up to a small monitor (using the VGA cable) without issue. I can hook my laptop up to the the TV using a mini-display-port to VGA adapter just fine. But when I hook the desktop up to the computer, it will show me the boot screen, but then the TV declares that there is "no signal".

From my laptop, the TV displays at 1920x1080p, from my girlfriend's laptop the default is 1280x1024. Using an extra monitor, I've tried setting the computer to both those resolutions, and quite a few others, switching the VGA cable over to the TV each time. No luck.

Windows tells me that the drivers for the graphics card are up-to-date. They also do seem to detect each other; when I plug the cable in to the TV, the computer makes the "device connected" noise, and sometimes the TV screen turns black for a few seconds before returning to it's purple "no signal" screen.

Is there anything I can do?

EDIT: I also found [this forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/305336) where some guy has problems connecting to the TV with Vista, but only 1366x768 works. That's not a resolution option that I see.

Comment: You might wish to keep an eye on my question as they may be related: http://superuser.com/q/639181/57130.

Comment: Can you find a manual for your TV (online or in the box)? My TV's manual explained that only certain resolutions will work on it. If you can find a way to set the resolution that Windows 7 uses as it boots it would probably fix it. I don't use Windows 7 (only XP) so I can't help further but I am looking to resolve a similar problem on XP now. If I find a solution that is relevant I will post it here.